# Split addresses into state, city, street address and postal code

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a script to scrape data for 20 thousands entries. The data has an address field. I want to split the address into street address, state, city and postal code.
I handled it on my own but the data is quite large and there are variations as well. Is there any service or module that i can use that can return the values i want from the address?
Eg:

```
481 Burnham Ave|Calumet City, IL 60409
```

This is the address I **scraped** from two line which is joined by '|'. I want to use some library which can tell the city name and state from this address so that i can remove them and get the address after further processing. The library or module should not be restricted to a country only and should be used for worldwide.

Comment: Why do you need alirary to do that..? Clearly the addresses are stored in a standard format in which first line is the street address,second the city,third the state and lastly the Postal code for that address just split the address on `','` and you're done i guess. You can change the logic based on countries if the adderess standards defer.Read this wikipedia article on [address standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address).

Comment: Could you add a more extensive sample of the raw data and the data you processed?

Comment: If, as you say, the formatting is different for your data, you will need something a bit more powerful. One option is to use [Google Place Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search). I am sure there are other options as well though.

Comment: C Hecht , yes thats what i am looking for. A service which can do it easily as there are a lot of variations and data consists of 40+ countries and 20,000 data.

Comment: Tranbi you can check this link https://coinatmradar.com/bitcoin_atm/31285/bitcoin-atm-general-bytes-birmingham-altadena-spirits/ . Here it looks simple but there are variations in addresses with the increase in data. So i need an online api or something like that which can do it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are storing the address in pandas dataframe, Write a function with the following string splits operation. and use apply on this column.

```
strr = '481 Burnham Ave|Calumet City, IL 60409'
st_name = strr.split('|')[0]
city_state = strr.split('|')[1].split(',')
city= city_state[0]
print(st_name)
print(city)
state = city_state[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
zip_code = city_state[1].strip().split(' ')[1]
print(state)
print(zip_code)
```

Output:

```
481 Burnham Ave
Calumet City
IL
60409
```

Comment: I have already done that but the problem is that there are variations for 40+ countries and 20 k data. So it is not possible to cover all variations. What is want is, i want to use some library/api where i can put the address and get the split address in the response.

Comment: Share some of the samples here... and try some open source address parser using python.